# How to generate waveform values for storing in an EEPROM?

Tags: eeprom, waveform

I need to program an old EEPROM with 16 different waveforms: triangle, rectangle, sine, etc.

Is there a method that can encode a given waveform into an array of values like you can do in a spreadsheet? My goal is to generate 16 such arrays according to wave patterns.

Comment: I remember hacking out such programs manually myself, not that hard if you know a bit of GUI programming on PC. Though I'm fairly sure it would be possible to do with Excel too.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use Excel then? It might be simpler for one-off projects than writing a C/Octave/Python program to do it.

Comment: Why don't you just write a simple program in your favorite programming language? A console app will suffice. You can spit out whatever format you like.

Comment: What format do you need the data in? Excel has ASCII Hex functions (DEC2HEX).

Comment: Use Excel, or any other programming language of your choice. If you don't program yet, then let me steer you towards python.

Comment: What speed? How many bits?

Comment: What is the part number of the EEPROM?

Comment: I'm not sure on close justification.  The question is a bit unclear (as in comments must be addressed), but how you'd generate a Lookup-Table seems quite valid to me.

Comment: Maybe the brand name "Excel" was flagged. So change that to the generic "spreadsheet".  But this seems like excessive nit-picking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some audio editing programs like [Audacity](https://www.audacityteam.org/) can generate sine, square, sawtooth, triangle, chirp, noise, and DTMF waveforms with a frequency, amplitude, duration, bit depth, and "sampling" frequency of your choice (I read you can also draw arbitrary waveforms with the Draw Tool in Audacity, but I have never tried that myself).

The result can be saved in several formats, including raw (just a series of values you can use for storing in your EEPROM).

You can, of course, also easily generate periodical series of values in just about any programming language or spreadsheet.

*Note: I mention Audacity because it is what I use myself to create such waveform arrays; no affiliation. Besides, it's free.*

Answer (score 1):

Since the EEPROM only stores bits as 0 or 1, you can try to store the waveform as discrete signals which occupy a value at any position in time and you can use 500 to 1000 or more samples of each waveform. If you have infinite discrete samples of a waveform, you get a continuous signal which is not really needed. if you are storing voltage signals, You can build a sampling table such as 3 bits can be used to indicate voltage from 0V to 8V.

Depending on the scale and granularity, you can choose more or less number of bits for each sample and also the number of samples of a waveform. In this way, you can have 3000 bits for a waveform as a example in a somewhat coarse representation. Separate each waveform with dummy bytes such as 0xFF.When you read the waveforms back from EEPROM, generate voltage levels with suitable algorithm and generate discrete waveforms. You would be generating discrete waveforms which work as continuous signals for practical purposes.

Comment: Most EEPROMs are organized into 8- or 16-bit wide words, though, so packing smaller samples into that space might be more complicated than you think. Especially parallel EEPROMs would require a fair bit more coding than just using 8-bit samples.

Comment: I didn't check which EEPROM he was referring to but I assumed that the width of each write or read transaction would be 16 or 32 bits. It can be complicated. If just 8 bit samples are used, each 7 bits can be used to represent between 0V to 8V depending on how many bits are set.  One bit bit can be used to indicate a positive or  negative voltage.. Each write or read to the EEPROM would be used only for one sample. I assume that two hundred samples may be enough for one time period of a waveform depending on the application.